Adjusting brightness is not workng and pressing brightness buttons cause system shutdown (while booting on discrete video card)
Recently I've bought Lenovo loq 16aph8, installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and faced several issues. One of them is the system crush (power off) when pressing brightness adjusting buttons (F5, F6). Otherwise sometimes it makes the screen black (zero brightness), sometimes it triggers microphone mute button (F4). I've tried to change and update grub settings like in these posts, but it didn't work:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/v97arf/problem_with_brightness_control_using_ubuntu_2204/
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=286357
Ask me about details, I am not sure what information is needed to solve this issue.
Some video driver details:
lshw -c video:

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:7a0-79f iomemory:7c0-7bf irq:75 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:7a00000000-7bffffffff memory:7c00000000-7c01ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:a1000000-a107ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: c2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: iomemory:7c0-7bf irq:43 memory:7c10000000-7c1fffffff memory:a1200000-a13fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:a1700000-a177ffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080

UPD: It seems that the problem is related to the graphic card drivers (nvidia). After booting in the dynamic mode with amd-graphics the problem disappears. Moreover, after booting again with discrete card the problem seemed solved and brightness button worked, however after several pressess - the system shutdown again and brightness was again set to the max level with the same problems with buttons. Additionaly, I've found exactly the same issue here:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/brightness-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04/224227
There's also a fix for older AMD Ryzen 7 6800h, but I have AMD Ryzen 7 7840HS I can't change brightness on ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

I partially fixed it by removing all redundant parameters from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and now it looks like GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.sg_display=0 amdgpu.backlight=0". First option prevent screen flickering, second fix brightness problem. BUT the system is still shutdown while adjusting brightness on GPU, so the problem persist in some sort of...

I fixed it. First of all - you need to clean up your GRUB settings using following steps:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
Add amdgpu.backlight=0 parameter to the end of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. In my case it looks like so: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.sg_display=0 amdgpu.backlight=0"
sudo update-grub

The steps above will fix brightness adjusting on GPU. To prevent system shutdown - you need to add several modules to the blacklist. (like in the post here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=286357&p=2). It seems like ideapad_laptop cause a problem. To adapt this answer for ubuntu do the following steps:

sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
Add to the end of the file lines:

blacklist button
blacklist tiny_power_button
blacklist ideapad_laptop


sudo update-initramfs -u

Final step: sudo reboot.
Note that this fix is only suitable for Lenovo laptops (at least because ideapad_laptop is lenovo-specific module). However the problem itself may be only happen with these laptops. Hope it will help someone.
